# If user types in file that is not present, inform and ask to retype file name

Tags: c#

So I have a prompt that asks the user to type in the location of a file. How do I make it so if the file is not there, the program reasks the user for the file location? Here is my current code. I have it in the original form, since I was messing around with it. I was getting sorta close, but no cigar. Thanks in advance!

edit: So, if a user types in c:/file.xml and it should be c:/file32.xml it will crash. How do I make it ask user to try again?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //asks user for location of the XML file
        Console.WriteLine("Enter location of XML file and XML file name please. Example - c:/xmlfile.xml");
        //XML files becomes "xmlfile"
        string xmlfile = Console.ReadLine();


        //takes xmlfile and runs it through XPATH
        string fileName = xmlfile;
        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(fileName);
        XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

        //Compile a standard XPath expression
        //Selects all of the names
        XPathExpression expr;
        expr = nav.Compile("/zabbix_export/templates/template/items/item/name | /zabbix_export/templates/template/items/item/description");
        XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);
```

Comment: So, if a user types in c:/file.xml and it should be c:/file32.xml it will crash. How do I make it ask user to try again?

Answer (score 2):

```
while (!File.Exists(xmlFile))
{
       Console.WriteLine("Please reenter a valid file name:");
        xmlfile = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep checking if the file exists till the user finally puts the right path in :)

```
string xmlFile;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter location of XML file and XML file name please. Example - c:/xmlfile.xml");
    xmlFile = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!File.Exists(xmlFile));
```

Comment: I am getting a error saying File does not exist. To be sure, I am placing the if in between my string xml file = Console.ReadLine(); and the //takes xmlfile and runs it through XPATH corrent? and then put the rest of the code in the brackets? like this                             `string xmlfile = Console.ReadLine();
            if (File.Exists(xmlfile))
             {

            //takes xmlfile and runs it through XPATH
            string fileName = xmlfile;
            XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(fileName);
            XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();`

Comment: Where did you place that? I keep getting errors. I am moving it around as I type.

Comment: @PolarisUser Sorry for that, now it should be error-free. After the loop finishes, you can be sure that `xmlFile` contains the path to existing file and you  can create `XPathDocument` from it.

Comment: I am still a little confused as to where I put the code. Everywhere I place it, I get errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(fileName);

while (doc == null)
{
    // display prompt
    // try to retrieve new value for doc
}

    XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
    //Compile a standard XPath expression
    //Selects all of the names
    XPathExpression expr;
    expr = nav.Compile("/zabbix_export/templates/template/items/item/name | /zabbix_export/templates/template/items/item/description");
    XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);
```